# Laravel 5.6 wildcard route not functioning as expected with domain

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, wildcard, laravel-routing

I'm using Laravel 5.6 and am trying to create a laravel route in my web file so that anything with the following URL: `/assets/*` would go through my controller. For instance, `/assets/page1/page2` or `/assets/js/somefile`, for some reason it only works when I literally type the following into my URL: `/assets/*`.

```php
Route::get('/assets/*', 'AssetsController@proxy');
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

That isn't how you would define a wildcard route. You have to define a parameter:

```
Route::get('assets/{asset}', ...);
```

This will only give you a single segment so you will then need to define a pattern for this parameter so it can actually catch the rest of the path:

```
Route::get('assets/{asset}', ...)->where('asset', '.*');
```

[Laravel 5.6 Docs - Routing - Route Parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-parameters)

[Laravel 5.6 Docs - Routing - Regular Expression Constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints) `where`

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::get('/assets/{catchAll}', 'AssetsController@proxy');
```

Is the correct syntax for wildcards in routes

Comment: Brilliant, however this only works for just one thing after `/assets/` such as `/assets/test` but as per my original question - potentially multiple: `/assets/page1/page2`, there could be one URL with one, or another URL with more than one.